# How to transfer a ASP.NET webpage from one PC to another?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2013

I had build a website in ASP.NET and C# using Visual studio 2013 and I published the website using IIS in windows.

Now I want to make some other PC as a server instead of current one.

For that do I need to install visual studio in the newer one or

Is it enough to simply copy the website folder to the new PC and publish that folder via IIS in new PC.

NOTE: I dont want want to compile the Website since I tested it already.

Answer (score 1):

no need to install Visual Studio again and Publish the website again using Visual Studio

Copy / pste will work fine

Just make sure you copy everything and that IIS is set up correctly

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, you right-click the project in Solution Explorer. Then, you should click the Publish on the right click menu. That will give you a publishable project files. You need to set IIS on your new computer, then you should put those publisable files into IIS. That's it.

Comment: can you elaborate the steps, 
when I click on publish it is asking for import,connection and settings, what are the inputs I have to give for them.